# Change default favicon of New tab when it gets open from an anchor tab for playing a video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, favicon

I am new in React, Help me in doing the following task.
Scenario : I have to open a video in a new tab with the help of anchor tag, which I solved easily as
<a target="_blank" href={} > My Video

**Now the issue is I have to change the favicon of that new tab which gets open when i click on my anchor tag for playing the video.**

Please help me in solving the issue to Change the default favicon of New tab when it gets open from an anchor tab for playing a video.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [React helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet).

It's a great component to use in such cases. If you have for example case of a metatag that you would like to overwrite deep in your application you can do so with very simple process.

```
<ParentComponent>
  <Helmet>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
  </Helmet>
  <ChildComponent>
  <Helmet>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon2.png"/>
  </Helmet>
  </ChildComponent>
</ParentComponent>
```

If this works out well, then things should be solved. In case of this solution not working, you can remove children from Helmet to change it's content.

Like so:

```
 <Helmet>
  {this.state.showDefaultFavicon && (<link href="/default-favicon.png" ... />)}
  {this.state.showVideoFavicon && (<link href="/video-favicon.png"... />)}
 </Helmet>
```